# Are there any good libraries for interpreting java language?

Tags: java, jvm, interpreter, static-typing

In lot of cases there is no need for classes to be explicitly compiled(i.e. running unit tests - I want them to be just *runnable*, not necessarily to be compiled & packaged).

I'm curious if there is any library for interpreting java.

Scala(static typed, runs on jvm) has interpreter built-in so in my understanding it should technically possible for java as well.

Comment: to run code in Java it must be compiled first, this question makes no sense

Comment: Hi Jarrod, thanks for the feedback. As I mentioned for scala(which also compiles to bytecode) interpreter does exist. I'm after something  similar for java. I don't care if that would be hidden incremental compilation with bytecode being held in memory - main purpose is to skip `java` step and go from .java file to running piece of logic.

Comment: It is definitely possible. I once wrote it (not complete though) for fun using Java Compiler API with byte codes in memory. You can also use Eclipse Java Compiler(ecj.jar) in which case you don't even need JDK, just JRE is enough.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - It does make technical sense.  There is nothing in the JLS that forbids a fully interpreted implementation of Java.  (Whether you can find a suitable interpreter is a different issue ...)

Comment: @MarimuthuMadasamy, using ecj sounds interesting, I'll give it a try

Comment: scala and groovy have to compile their code to bytecode, there is no way around it, they do the `javac` step even if it is hidden there is no getting around it if you want to run the code in the JVM. this question is like saying *I want to eat my cake but I don't want to have to cook the ingredients before hand.*

Comment: Yeah, that exactly what I'm asking for!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is too old. It is not clear what OP wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go a look at BeanShell. It's a Java interpreter. It may be a bit dated, I don't know if it supports generics for example, but you should take a look at it. It probably fits what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on beanshell (http://www.beanshell.org).